# Hazrlcast: write-behind works unstable

Tags: persistence, hazelcast

I have a process that populates data into map with persistence periodically. To be more exact there are two nodes: storage node with persistence enabled and cache maps defined and a lite client node started with 'lite' option and no map defined. Connection between nodes does look good. During testing I found out that only around a half of populated data is actually flown into persistence though all data is in cache. I can confirm this by browsing the cache map and via JMX stats. I can't indicate dependencies on the data or time it is populated.

Could someone please advise where the investigation should start from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only my own fault. I did not provide 'lite' option to the populator properly so data is distributed between nodes and only written on the storage side as lite client does not have any persistence set up. I did not remove the question to prevent someone else from this silly failure.